# Codeigniter: Display uploaded image

Tags: image, codeigniter, upload

I just uploaded an image with an encrypted filename and placed it in an *uploads* folder outside of web root. I never thought this through...since the image is outside of web root, how do I display it on my page?

My layout:

```
example.app
  Lsystem
  Lapplication
  Luploads
    -image.jpg
public
  -index.php
```

How can I display *image.jpg* if it's outside of web root?

Comment: There is one way you could do it but you have to modify the httpd.conf and create an alias.  Most web hosts don't allow you to do this though

Comment: Here's an idea: What if I look for the file then copy it to a folder *within* web root?

Comment: You can also look into symlinks if you are wanting to keep it outside the webroot

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your upload folder is

```
    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'public/uploads/img/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';
```

You can use something how that in your layout:

```
<img src='/public/uploads/img/nameofyourimage.jpg'>
```